# I want to read a text file and display the contents of the file in 8*8 array form

Tags: java, file

Example:
Suppose my file is:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7  
8
```

I want to display it as:

```
1 2 3 4  
5 6 7 8
```

I have been able to read from the file and have been able to display the file contents.
Iv'e used this approach to read from file and display, but I am not able to figure out a way to bring it into 8*8 array form.

```
public class FileRead  
{
public static void printRow(int[] row) 
{
    for (int k : row) 
    {
        System.out.print(k);
        System.out.print("\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }



  public static void main(String[] args)
{
File file = new File("filepath");

int i,j;
int row = 8;
int column = 8;
int [][] myArray = new int [row][column];
try 
{

   Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
    {
    int k = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print(k);
        System.out.print("\t");
        }
    System.out.println();


   /*for(int[] row : myArray) 
    {
        printRow(row);
    }*/

    sc.close();
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

I'm getting output in this form:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
 BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filepath"));
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
  int k = sc.nextInt();
  if(iRow < myArray.length && iColumn < myArray[iRow].length) 
  {
    myArray[iRow][iColumn] = k;
iColumn++;
if(iColumn == myArray[iRow].length)  
{
 iColumn = 0;
 iRow++;
}
 }

  System.out.print(myArray[iRow][iColumn]);
 }
  }
```

Comment: Your "I want to display it as" doesn't really match the "8x8 array form", it's more like a 2x4... which is more fitting to the 8 input elements. So what do you mean by "8x8 array form"?

Comment: I just used it as an example to describe  what I actually want to implement. Whatever be the file content, I want to read and display it in a grid form.

Answer (score 0):

```
int iRow = 0; //Counter row
int iColumn = 0;  //Counter column
int [][] myArray = new int [row][column];
... while ...
int k = sc.nextInt;
if(iRow < myArray.length && iColumn < myArray[iRow].length) // the counter cant be greater than the array row; same with column
{
  myArray[iRow][iColumn] = k;
  iColumn++;
  if(iColumn == myArray[iRow].length)  //if you access the last column; go to the next row
  {
     iColumn = 0;
     iRow++;
  }


}
```

This code will fill your array[][].

Comment: I tried this, but when I want to print the 2d array, I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. Could you help me with this?

Comment: After the  `while` you have to `for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
   {
    for (int j = 0; j < myArray [i].length; j++)
    {
     System.out.print(myArray[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
   }`

Comment: Build successful but, it does'nt display any output. @Wufo

Answer (score 0):

Just add into you loop

```
//{...}
int newLineAfter = 4;

for (int k: row) {
 System.out.print(k);
 System.out.print("\t");
 //when k will be 4*n- 4, 8, 12, 16... 
 if (k % newLineAfter == 0) {
  System.out.println();
 }
}
System.out.println();
//{...}
```

% is modulo operator, it returns the remainder after the whole division
eg.

```
1 % 2 = 2
2 % 2 = 0 
3 % 2 = 1 
4 % 2 = 0

8 % 4 = 0 
9 % 4 = 1 
10 % 4 = 2
```